# trying to send JSON data over socket but and the reciving end is single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: json, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to send JSON data of python3 socket, but on the receiving end the double quotes get turned into single quotes so I can not read it

Sending

```py
server_name = "One"

response_data = {"error": "false", "data": "Success", "Server": server_name}
response_request = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" + response_data

sock.send(response_request.encode())
sock.close()
```

Receive

```
response = requests.get("http://localhost/")
print(response.text)
{'error': 'false', 'data': 'Success', 'Server': server_name}
```

The doubles quotes get changed to single quotes

But if I send

```py
"""HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n{"error": "false", "data": "Success"}"""
```

It will not change the double quotes but I can not send the server_name variable

Answer (score 1):

Your server doesn't work, but to make a working server you need to `json.dumps` the dictionary object into a string.  Here's a minimal working JSON server that sets the content type header and can be read by the `requests` module:

server.py

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        server_name = "One"
        response_data = {"error": "false", "data": "Success", "Server": server_name}
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response_data).encode())

httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8080), Server)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

client.py

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/")
print(response.text)    # returns string
print(response.json())  # returns parsed JSON object (dict in this case)
```

Output (client):

```
{"error": "false", "data": "Success", "Server": "One"}
{'error': 'false', 'data': 'Success', 'Server': 'One'}
```